# Angular 14 does't work on Windows XP with Chrome 49

Tags: angular

After update project to Angular 14, our application does't work on Windows XP with Chrome 49(this version is latest for XP).

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

in scripts.js file

We try to add this in .browserslistrc

```
last 2 Chrome version or Chrome 49
```

... nothing change.

How to solve this problem? Maybe we need to add some pollyfils?

Comment: You can configure the JS Version in your `tsconfig.app.json` by adding `"module": "es2015"` to the `compilerOptions` object. Should be no need for polyfills or babel. I don't know if this will fix your issue though, it seems very niche.

Comment: I need change module or target in tsconfig.app.json?

Comment: do you know if angular 14 itself supports your OS + browser combination?

Comment: changing target to es2015 or es5 does't help